# Convert Infix expression to Postfix

Tags: stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

Convert the following infix expression to postfix:

```
True Or False And Not False Or False [Comptt 2005]
```

According to me, The answer should be:

```
True false false not and or false or
```

Considering the precedence order Not>and>or 
((true or (false and (not false))) or false)

But according to the book, the answer is:

True False Or False Not and False or

They did it by: (((True or False)And (Not False))Or False)

Comment: Is the precedence of "and" higher than "or" stated in the book, a convention for the genre, or your own invention?  In many languages, both operations have the same precedence (and IMHO, anything else is horribly confusing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is right.One clear mistake in the book answer is that precendence of conditional or is not greater than conditional and therefore the parenthesized expression would be:

((True Or (False and (NOTFalse)))Or False).